# emacs map key to command like vim

Tags: vim, emacs

I set my own map `:map <C-j> :tab split<CR>:exec "tjump ".expand("<cword>")<CR>` in ~/.vimrc file to make `ctrl + j` as a shortcut to navigate to the definition, with `tjump`, if there is multiple match of the fuction that the cursor is on, then `vim` prompts to choose from all the matches, but when moving to `emacs`, I don't know how to do this, I google it, but did not get useful suggestions, can some veterens share how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with vim, but it sounds like you're asking to bind `C-j` to a command that will jump to the definition of the function name the cursor is on.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-j") #'xref-find-definitions)
```

`xref-find-definitions` is bound to `M-.` by default.

Personally, I use GNU global, and the [gxref](https://github.com/dedi/gxref) package.  gxref just adds another backend to [xref](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Xref.html), so that it works with global in addition to etags.